# jQuery animations not working / behaving strangely in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

I'm developing a personal website, http://www.miketurley.com.

In any Webkit browser (Chrome, Safari) or Firefox, when you mouse-over the text on my site's opening screen, you get a slick animation which slides the text around and reveals the menu ("waking up" my website.)  This may not be too necessary, but I like it and I think it's appropriate to showcase skills like that on my portfolio website.

Anyway, if you go to my website in Internet Explorer, the animations do not appear at all.  The same duration of time goes by, and then the page "snaps" into the post-animation state in one frame, with no motion in between.

How can I fix this?

An explanation of this particular animation along with source code is available here: http://www.miketurley.com/index_explain.html

Comment: Why the need for so much eval()?

Comment: yeah... I really need to rewrite that without all the eval().  I just was getting frustrated with certain characters not being escaped properly and made all the animate calls into strings.  It's ugly, I know.  I'll fix it sooner or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving `eval` aside, you site is failing to quirks mode in IE. Using dev tools I switched to different Document Mode and the animations ran just nice. Can't find out what activates quirks right now but you have an issue to investigate. Start with passing the [strict validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.miketurley.com%2F) or moving to transitional or html5 `<!doctype html>`